# Sort & Ranking Functions in Excel for Time AND Number Values in one Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, sorting

I have a spreadsheet that is being used to track and score a fitness competition, each workout has a time cap, so athletes that complete the workout under the time cut off are given a time as their score, while athletes that do not finish the full workout are given their "rep count" as a score.

For example a workout has a 10 minute time cap and a total of 165 reps.

- Athlete A finishes all 165 reps in 8:30.00
- Athlete B only completes 145 reps in 10 minutes

Athletes A score entered into the "Score" column is therefore `8.30` while Athlete B's score is `145`.

I'm trying (but have yet to succeed) to do two things with this data:

1. Have the time/reps column be sorted in ascending order to show first the fastest time and last the lowest rep count.
2. Create a formula that wil calculate the ranking of the athlete (1st-40th), taking into account the possibility of tie - in which case both athletes need to be assigned the same position and the subsequent athlete assigned the tied positions + 1 (eg 1, T2, T2, 4).

Comment: What have you tried already? Where are you stuck? Do you need a formula (or several formulas) or VBA?

Comment: POINT 1: I've been able to figure it out if I put the time and reps in separate columns Column C - Time, Column D - Reps, then sort by Time then by reps. This works, however it throws off the ranking formula as that now references two different columns instead of one column. 

POINT 2: On the ranking formula, I've done a simple IF statement, which basically says: If current score = to previous score then current position = previous position, if not then current position = previous position + 1. This works, until I get a tie and then it fails.

Comment: Can you use VBA (a macro)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a formula for you.  This assumes your numbers are in column B

```
=IF(B5>1,COUNTIF(B:B,"<1")+RANK(B5,B:B,0),RANK(B5,B:B,1))
```

How it works

**If(B1>1** Since times are stored as fractions of days all times less then 24 hours will be less then 1 (This assumes there isn't anyone with zero reps) If this is true we are looking at reps and higher reps should be ranked higher

**COUNTIF(B:B,"<1")+RANK(B5,B:B,0)** Countif will count the number of people with times and then you add the rank (with highest number being 1) add these two together gives you your proper rank.

**RANK(B1,B:B,1)** Normal rank lower time is better lowest time is 1

Comment: Very impressive +1

Comment: You sir and a legend! Seriously. Thank you so much, it works perfectly! Wow.

Comment: @Rory if this answers your question, be sure to click the green checkmark next to it to indicate solved

Comment: @Raystafarian cheers. It's solved! Thank you!